# Поиск класса html посредством javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть html разметка:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Задача:

Если есть в разметке `div` с классом `sidebar`, нужно `div` с классом `content` добавить еще один класс right.

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Покажите что уже пробовали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Умещаю всё в одну строку:

```js
document.querySelector('div.sidebar') ? document.querySelector('div.content').classList.add('right') : null
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">1</div>
    <div class="content">2</div>
</div>
```

А если делать красивый код тогда вот:

```js
document.querySelector('div.sidebar')
  ? document.querySelector('div.content').classList.add('right')
  : null
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">1</div>
    <div class="content">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой подход:

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper'); //Здесь мы находим "главного" нужной нам разметки наших `.sidebar` и `.content`.

if (wrapper.querySelector('.sidebar') { // чтобы уже здесь искать класс `.sidebar` только в нужном родителе
   wrapper.querySelector('.content').classList.add('right'); //и, если найдём, добавить класс `.right` к элементу `.content`
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ немного неправильный, вот к примеру если в `.wrapper` будет ребёнок с классом `.sidebar`, но он будет не `div`-ом, а к примеру `span`-ом. А в задаче написано, что нужно именно изменить `div` только если будет `div` с классом `sidebar`. Это также касается и `.content` в котором не уточнён элемент.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Не самая лучшая практика делать выборку по тегу с классом, лучше использовать ```class``` без указания тега. Маловероятно, что сайдбар будет создан с помощью ```span```, для него лучше использовать ```aside```

Comment: @soledar10 я привёл `span` как пример, если вы не читали мой комментарий полностью, то критиковать вы не можете. Цитата: "Ваш ответ немного неправильный, вот **к примеру если...**"

Comment: @soledar10 и по задаче кстати нужны именно `div`-ы, а не любые теги с вышеупомянутым классом.

Comment: @ΝNL993 - Нет никакой критики, вполне возможно автор не в курсе, что для семантики лучше использовать теги ```html5```, поэтому и написал, что в данном случае использование селектора тег с классом не целесообразно.

Answer (score 1):

В условии было именно про добавить класс `right`, но вообще такие задачи на условное форматирование блока часто могут быть решены через селекторы, без javascript. Посмотрите, может, в вашем случае такое тоже применимо.

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid tomato;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar + .content {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">wrapper without sidebar
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">wrapper WITH sidebar
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле тут несколько способов решить задачу, в зависимоти от того что именно нужно:

- Если во всей разметке может быть только 1 `div.sidebar` и 1 `div.content` и они могут быть расположены где угодно (т.е. не факт что они будут соседями), то можно сделать так:

```js
document.querySelector('div.sidebar') ? document.querySelector('div.content').classList.add('right') : null;

// Ну или более сокращённо, то можно так

document.querySelector('div.sidebar') && document.querySelector('div.content').classList.add('right');
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

- Если во всей разметке может быть хотябы 1 `div.sidebar` и сколь угодно много `div.content` и они могут быть расположены где угодно, то можно сделать так:

```js
const isSidebarExists = document.querySelector('div.sidebar') !== null;

if (isSidebarExists) {
  document.querySelectorAll('div.content').forEach(content => content.classList.add('right'));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

- Если во всей разметке может быть только 1 `div.sidebar` и 1 `div.content` и они обязательно соседи, то можно сделать так:

```js
// Если content будет находится непосредственно после sidebar

document.querySelector('div.sidebar + div.content')?.classList.add('right');

// Если у content и sidebar просто общий предок, но content всё равно идёт после sidebar

document.querySelector('div.sidebar ~ div.content')?.classList.add('right');

// Если у content и sidebar просто общий предок

document.querySelector('div.sidebar').parentNode.querySelector(':scope > div.content')?.classList.add('right')
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

- Если во всей разметке может быть сколь угодно много `div.sidebar` и для каждого из них может быть существует 1 соседний `div.content`, то можно сделать так:

```js
// Если content находится непосредственно после sidebar

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar').forEach(sidebar => {
  sidebar.parentNode.querySelector('div.sidebar + div.content')?.classList.add('right');
})


// Если у content и sidebar просто общий предок, но content всё равно идёт после sidebar

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar').forEach(sidebar => {
  sidebar.parentNode.querySelector('div.sidebar ~ div.content')?.classList.add('right');
})


// Если у content и sidebar просто общий предок

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar').forEach(sidebar => {
  sidebar.parentNode.querySelector(':scope > div.content')?.classList.add('right');
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

- Если во всей разметке может быть сколь угодно много `div.sidebar` и для каждого из них может быть существует сколь угодно много соседних `div.content`, то можно сделать так:

```js
// Если у content и sidebar просто общий предок, но content всё равно идёт после sidebar

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar').forEach(sidebar => {
  sidebar.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar ~ div.content').forEach(content => {
    content.classList.add('right');
  });
})


// Если у content и sidebar просто общий предок

document.querySelectorAll('div.sidebar').forEach(sidebar => {
  sidebar.parentNode.querySelectorAll(':scope > div.content').forEach(content => {
    content.classList.add('right');
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Но будьте осторожны на счёт [:scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) его не поддерживает IE